# Start showing new php page in middle of the content

Tags: php, forms

I've been looking ofr a while but I'ven't found any question that solves my question:

I've a php page with some forms, it's a long page and users may use one or some of the forms each time they connect to the website. When an users submits one of the forms the forms calls the same page but with the data updated (that works good for me).

The problem is that I would like that after submiting any form, the new page starts in middle of the scroll where the form submited is, so the user hasn't to go to the start of the page.

I'm not sure if this can be done with php or I need javascript (i don't know anything about javascript yet).

Comment: you can target the location on relaod with  an anchor `<a href="#FORM99">something or blank</a>` then add the #FORM99 to the reolad url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `id` to navigate between elements in a page. Put `#` in `action` attribute when the user submits the form the browser will navigate to the form location

Example

```
 <form id="example" action="yourpage.php#example" method=...>

 <form id="example2" action="yourpage.php#example2" method=...>
```